# head.js with asp.net masterpage throwing HTML Parsing Error

Tags: jquery, head.js

Im trying to use head.js to load the javascript files in my asp.net page that uses a masterpage (and usercontrols) to ensure they are more self-contained.

but i am getting this error "**HTML Parsing Error:Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed**" when the page loaded up.

the head.js is referenced in the master page

and basically i have the following script in one of the one contentholder in the actual aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    head.js("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js", function() {

        alert('load done');

    });

</script>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I use `head.js` in masterpages but I never had a problem like that, are you using `head.ready` instead `$(document).ready` ?

Comment: Are you sure the error is from head.js and not elsewhere?

Comment: look like the error only occurs in IE. No error for firefox and chrome.

Comment: In which version of IE this bug was reproducable? May be this issue is not actual now and  you can put some comment as answer and close question as answered